# How do I reset all Commerce order references?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

By default, Commerce uses the `{{number[:7]}}` format to set an order's reference on order completion. Now (after the site already has orders and I can no longer reset the site's data), I need to use a different format for existing orders, because we're going to use it as the invoice number, which has to be sequential.

Is there a way to `reset` the order's references in such a way that I can set the format to `{{object.dateCompleted|date('y')}}-{{ seq(object.dateCompleted|date('y'), 6) }}`, run a script (for instance) and give all orders a new reference (2021-000001, 2021-000002, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you change the mini template for your order numbers, Commerce will start using that new thing...if you want the numbers part to reset, just use a new sequence name in the template.

You can start it at a particular number, too, if you wish, e.g. to start at 2022-000005:

```
{{ object.dateCompleted|date('y') ~ '-' ~ (seq("some_new_name",6) + 5) }}
```

If you want to remap existing orders to this format, you will probably be best doing that via some migration/module code...

Basically...loop over the orders in question and:

```php
$order->reference = $whatever;
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($order);
```